# Is there a doc explaining the options for tensors_to_detections_calculator.cc?

Tags: mediapipe

I have some difficulty to figure out the best values to set for the options of `tensors_to_detections_calculator.cc`.

Especially the x/y_scale and `apply_exponential_on_box_size`.

Wondering if there is a doc explaining how to set these options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the settings correspond to the training configuration for my ssd model (box encoder session)